# Call PL/SQL block in unix script

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to call pl/sql block in unix script using sqlplus. I just tried to print a statement but nothing is getting printed and I am not getting any error as well.

```
Result=`sqlplus -s $TgtUsrID/$TgtPswd@$TgtServer <<eof
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
END;
eof
`
current_time=`date`
echo " Script execution   finished at $current_time"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to prepend the variable(`Result`) with the dollar operator after the last `EOF`
along with an `echo` command such as

```
Result=`sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
 conn $TgtUsrID/$TgtPswd@$TgtServer
 whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
 set feedback off

 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
 BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
 END;
 /
EOF`

echo $Result    
echo Script execution finished at $(date)
```

would yield such a result

```
Hello World!
Script execution finished at Tue Feb 14 00:15:51 +03 2021
```

where quotes for the description after the last `echo` is redundant, and prefer using connection with `/nolog` as being securer, since the password of the schema would be unveiled whenever `ps -ef` command issued in the current case.

Comment: Why is the timestamp over 2 week ago?

Comment: well I didn't notice what the time within my virtual machine displays exactly :) @wallyk

Comment: I see.  You have one of them old-fashioned slow virtual machines.....   ;-)

Comment: just as an aside about coding efficiency ... instead of two lines "current_time=`date`" and "echo Script execution finished at $current_time", you could / should just simply "echo Script execution finished at $(date)"

Comment: @EdStevens:  Forget *coding efficiency*.  For me it is all about code verbosity and wondering if `current_time` was going to be used again somewhere.

Comment: @wallyk -  well, by 'code efficiency' I really meant in _writing_ the code, not in the execution of it.  Certainly if I need to reference the same value multiple times I'd put it in its own variable.  But in this case, where it is displaying the current time of a given activity it's pointless to capture the current time in a variable when there is already a built-in variable.  Note that "echo `date` " is the same as "echo $(date) ".